# MariaDB SELECT all records for only accounts expiring within 30 days

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How do I *only* `SELECT` records using MariaDB whose accounts are set to expire in 30 days based off of the `max()` expiration date?

**What *not* to `SELECT`**: if today is December 7, 2017 and below the account "a" has a maximum expiration date of June 1st of 2018 then absolutely no records should be returned for account "a" with the desired `SELECT` query regardless of the fact that this table *also* contains rows for account "a" that are older than today's date.

**What *should* be selected:** account "b" has two records and it's `max()` record is less than 30 days; the row `id` 4 is what row *should* be returned from the desired `SELECT` query.

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | account | expiration |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | a       | 2017-01-01 |
| 2  | a       | 2018-06-01 |
| 3  | b       | 2017-01-01 |
| 4  | b       | 2018-01-01 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I've spent a bit of time on this in various aspects though my most rigorous testing ultimately fails. Here is one bit that I've got working:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(expiration, '%Y-%m-%d'),CURDATE()) AS days_left FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You already notice you want `MAX`.
2. You want `MAX` per account, which translates to `GROUP BY account` in SQL.
3. You only want to show certain accounts, namely those with `MAX` within a particular date range. Criteria on aggregations belong in the `HAVING` clause.

Hence:

```
select account
from mytable
group by account
having max(expiration) between current_date and current_date + interval 30 day;
```

Comment: This looks good on my initial tests! After a meal and a few more tests I'll accept it, +1 just because I've never seen `HAVING`.

Comment: Reading tutorials on `HAVING` and looking at my own direct tests I suppose you could say I'm `HAVING` this accepted as the right answer. Thank you! :-)